# Group By with different primary key column and aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID
      ,A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID
      ,CASE WHEN DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT > 0 THEN DP_DEPOSIT_DATE
                  ELSE A.VALUATION_DATE 
         END AS VALUATION_DATE
         ,case when DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT < 0 THEN DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT
          when DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT > 0 THEN DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT
         WHEN DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT> 0 THEN DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT
         WHEN WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL>0 THEN WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL * -1
         WHEN IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT>0 THEN IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT
         ELSE 0
         END AS MPR
      ,B.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE AS IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE
      ,IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT
      ,DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT
      ,0.00 DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT
      ,DP_DEPOSIT_DATE
      ,WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL 
      FROM PANST_ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY AS A
        INNER JOIN (select C.VALUATION_DATE, C.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID, MAX(C.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE) "IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE" 
                          from (SELECT DISTINCT A.VALUATION_DATE, A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID, B.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE, A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID
                              FROM PANST_ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY AS A
                              INNER JOIN (  SELECT DISTINCT IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE, ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID, VALUATION_DATE, BENEFIT_SEQ, DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT, ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID
                                                  FROM  PANST_ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY 
                                                  WHERE ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID = 168811 
                                                  AND (IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT > 0 
                                                  OR DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT > 0 
                                                  OR WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL > 0)) AS B ON A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID = B.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID AND A.VALUATION_DATE = B.VALUATION_DATE AND A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID = B.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID
                          WHERE A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID = 168811) AS C
                          GROUP BY C.VALUATION_DATE, C.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID ) AS B ON A.VALUATION_DATE=B.VALUATION_DATE
                                                                                                      AND A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID=B.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID
                                                                                                      --AND A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID = B.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID
WHERE A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID = 168811 AND ((IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT > 0 AND 
B.VALUATION_DATE > 20190220)
OR (DP_DEPOSIT_DATE  >= 20190220) OR WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL > 0) 

UNION SELECT A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID
      ,A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID
      ,CASE WHEN DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT > 0 THEN DP_DEPOSIT_DATE
                  ELSE A.VALUATION_DATE 
            END AS VALUATION_DATE
        ,case when DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT < 0 THEN DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT
          when DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT > 0 THEN DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT
         WHEN DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT> 0 THEN DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT
         WHEN WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL>0 THEN WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL * -1
         WHEN IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT>0 THEN IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT
         ELSE 0
         END AS MPR
        
      ,B.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE AS IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE
      ,IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT
      ,0.00 DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT
      ,DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT
      ,DP_DEPOSIT_DATE
      ,WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL 
      FROM PANST_ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY AS A
        INNER JOIN (select C.VALUATION_DATE, C.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID, MAX(C.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE) "IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE" 
                          from (SELECT DISTINCT A.VALUATION_DATE, A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID, B.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE, A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID
                              FROM PANST_ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY AS A
                              INNER JOIN (  SELECT DISTINCT IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE, ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID, VALUATION_DATE, BENEFIT_SEQ, DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT, ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID
                                                  FROM  PANST_ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY 
                                                  WHERE ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID = 168811 
                                                  AND (IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT > 0 
                                                 -- OR DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT > 0 
                                                  OR WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL > 0)) AS B ON A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID = B.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID AND A.VALUATION_DATE = B.VALUATION_DATE AND A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID = B.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID
                          WHERE A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID = 168811) AS C
                          GROUP BY C.VALUATION_DATE, C.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID ) AS B ON A.VALUATION_DATE=B.VALUATION_DATE
                                                                                                      AND A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID=B.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID
      WHERE A.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID = 168811 AND ((IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT > 0 AND 
      B.VALUATION_DATE > 20190220)
      OR (DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT > 0 AND DP_DEPOSIT_DATE  >= 20190220) OR WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL > 0)
```

This query produces the following result:

[image]

and the resultset that I want should be like:

[image]

There should be only one row for each VALUATION_DATE column value after calculating SUM(MPR) and SUM(DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT) column and ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID column value should be picked up of MAX(MPR). I tried a lot but I think it's not possible. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two highlighted records are not from the same union part (One from the select above the union and the other from the select below the union) then adding aggregate functions to each of those queries won't work. Consider removing the union and combine the two conditions in one select statement or wrap a CTE around this statement and do the aggregation on that result.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
    /* Replace this test data with your query */
    SELECT
        2122807 AS ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID,
        168811 AS ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID,
        20190220 AS VALUATION_DATE,
        -9763.03 AS MPR,
        0 AS IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE,
        0 AS IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT,
        -9763.03 AS DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT,
        0 AS DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT,
        20190220 AS DP_DEPOSIT_DATE,
        0 AS WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL
    UNION
    SELECT
        2122808 AS ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID,
        168811 AS ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID,
        20190220 AS VALUATION_DATE,
        20549.50 AS MPR,
        0 AS IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE,
        0 AS IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT,
        20549.50 AS DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT,
        0 AS DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT,
        20190220 AS DP_DEPOSIT_DATE,
        0 AS WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL
),
CTE2 AS (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VALUATION_DATE ORDER BY MPR DESC) AS RowNumber, 
    ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID,
    VALUATION_DATE
FROM CTE1
)
SELECT
    C2.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID,
    C1.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID,
    C1.VALUATION_DATE,
    SUM(C1.MPR) AS MPR,
    C1.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE,
    C1.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT,
    SUM(C1.DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT) AS DP_GROSS_DEPOSIT,
    C1.DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT,
    C1.DP_DEPOSIT_DATE,
    C1.WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL
FROM CTE1 AS C1
    JOIN CTE2 AS C2 ON
        C1.VALUATION_DATE = C2.VALUATION_DATE
        AND C2.RowNumber = 1
GROUP BY
    C2.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID,
    C1.ANNUAL_STATEMENT_ID,
    C1.VALUATION_DATE,
    C1.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_RATE,
    C1.IN_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT,
    C1.DP_CURRENT_INTEREST_AMOUNT,
    C1.DP_DEPOSIT_DATE,
    C1.WD_GROSS_WITHDRAWAL
```

This query will aggregate the values from both selects in the union and will select the ANNUAL_STATEMENT_MPR_ACTIVITY_ID value of the highest MPR value by using the RowNumber field where RowNumber = 1 is the highest MPR value. (Consider renaming the CTEs to something more meaningful within your context)